# Post Tweets to Twitter from FaceBook using ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, twitter

I have created a facebook application using FaceBook ToolKit for .Net, What I am trying to do is create a WebApp for FaceBook which allows users to tweet.

I have also read about twitterizer library, that allows ASP.Net to create Apps for Twitter but it comes with OAuth authentication where a user is redirected to Twitter.com.

What I am trying to do is once user has given permission the app will accept username and password for their twitter account and then using Twitterizer library it will post their tweets.

All I need is a little guidance

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You have to use OAuth.

Twitter has no longer supports Basic HTTP Auth, and now requires OAuth for **all Twitter Applications**. You no longer need to have your app use their twitter username/password. That's the point of OAuth.

This is very similar to how Facebook App authorizations work. When someone wants to use your facebook app, they have to login to Facebook, and give your app permission to use your information.

It's the same thing with Twitter now. You will need to get a twitter API key for your app, then when users first want to tweet, you will make an OAuth request with your API key to Twitter, which will have your users first login to Twitter, then authorize your application.

After that process, you application will be able to "post" users tweets to their respective twitter accounts.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but you describe a situation when different users a re going to post tweets from some web site, but what should i do if i'm going to post information to my own twitter account from my web site? I found a lot of examples but they all require a new authentication session  to get a token before posting any tweets...How to make a permanent authorization for my web site and my account?